# Shairport on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Anyway to get work latest [shairport](https://github.com/abrasive/shairport) on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit desktop? I tried nearly all tutorials. No success. It opens application, says listening connections. But not visible in network

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'd like to try Shairport Sync. It runs on Ubuntu 14.04. It has evolved a fair bit from the original Shairport.

https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. I created a script for installing shairport from the 'master'-repository ([Shairport installer](https://github.com/y-nut/Shairport-installer)), which worked perfectly on Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon and Ubuntu 12.04 but now I have the same error as the blogger has posted on Ubuntu 14.04, why but why?

Would Dumindu Mahawela be able to explain how those packages helps anything?
Usually when I run the shairport it stays running in the terminal after opening a port but now it seems that it exits out immediately:

'# ~/Documents/shairport-master$ ./shairport -a 'Shairport' -d 
Listening for connections.
3058
'# ~/Documents/shairport-master$  (This line is usually not there when it works!)

Answer (score 0):

**libshairport** is in [Main Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shairport&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)

Can be Install as follows

```
sudo apt-get install libshairport1 libshairport-dev
```